# How to remove bad entry in home directory

Tags: 16.04, command-line, files, home-directory, rm

My home directory looks like this:

```
# ls -lt
total 417656
drwxrwxr-x 2 ljohnson ljohnson 427577344 May  9 08:48 2z9TnVLzmf
drwxr-xr-x 4 ljohnson ljohnson      4096 May  9 07:42 transmission
drwxr-xr-x 6 ljohnson ljohnson      4096 Apr  3 13:37 Downloads
drwxrwxr-x 5 ljohnson ljohnson      4096 Mar 28 07:25 Desktop
drwxrwxr-x 2 ljohnson ljohnson      4096 Sep 17  2017 saa7164
...
```

Where the size of `2z9TnVLzmf` is a problem.

Efforts to remove such as `# rm -rf` have proved futile.

`#ls 2z9TnVLzmf` returns no result and has to be canceled.

Update:  fsck is set to run at every boot for this relatively small partition

```
# df -hT | grep /dev/
/dev/sdc1      ext4       63G   60G  361M 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G   16M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1      xfs       2.8T  1.5T  1.3T  54% /pvr
/dev/sda1      xfs       4.6T  2.9T  1.7T  64% /pvu
/dev/sdc3      xfs       395G  101G  294G  26% /pvt
/dev/sdd1      xfs       1.9T 1023G  840G  55% /pvs
```

Comment: what's in the files? are they text or folders?

Comment: I am trying to get rid of some impossible to delete files as well... the hard drive got unplugged during delete and now they won't delete... I fear formatting the drive is my only option.

Comment: Have you run `fsck` on the partition ? Shold have been run automatically at boot...

Comment: have you tried to force it: rm -rf

Comment: "Update: fsck is set to run at every boot for this relatively small partition" and is that done with or without the -D option? "#ls 2z9TnVLzmf returns no result and has to be canceled." Why cancel? It will take a while to return  a result. We are talking about 4.2Gb (of whatever it is ;) ) Also: an "rm" ALSO will take a very long time

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/169215/huge-directory-not-files-inside-but-directory-itself  has an accepted answer so the problem got fixed.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thnx for the great suggestions. This is a modest HT Ubuntu 16 server in a remote location which has been running 24/7 since Ubuntu 10 and  difficult to physically reach. You were right about rm taking a long time..! :)

Comment: glad you got it sorted :) +1 from me

Comment: If it still runs Ubuntu 10.04 (considering that running 24/7 prevents release upgrades) it is over 4 years past the end of its support life.

Comment: It runs 16.04 LTS currently, is upgraded regularly w/o power off. 18.04 LTS upgrade not available until after 18.04.1 late July per release notes  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got a Kali USB stick, shut her down, pulled other discs, and booted into Kali.

```
# lsblk
# e2fsck -f -C 0 /dev/sda1
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# cd /mnt/home/ljohnson/
# rm -rf 2z9TnVLzmf
```

`rm` ran for at least 45 minutes but less than two hours but `2z9TnVLzmf` is gone.

Now the partition is %36

```
# df -hT | grep /dev/
/dev/sda1      ext4       63G   21G   39G  36% /
/dev/sdc1      xfs       2.8T  1.5T  1.3T  53% /pvr
/dev/sdb1      xfs       1.9T 1010G  853G  55% /pvs
/dev/sde1      xfs       4.6T  2.9T  1.8T  62% /pvu
/dev/sda3      xfs       395G  101G  294G  26% /pvt
```